# How can I escape an exclamation point in the PS1 environment variable?

Tags: bash, quoting, prompt

It is substituted with the history number even if I try to escape it with a backslash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to escape it if you just want an exclamation mark in the prompt.

```
PS1='foobar!'
```

See what happens.

Comment: It works with single quotes, but the problem is, I need to use double quotes because my PS1 uses `tput` codes.

Comment: Then do this. PS1='foorbar!'"your other code"

Comment: Oh, thanks! I knew I was being a dummy somewhere! EDIT: I was actually being a dummy in multiple places, because I just realized that my attempts to "escape" the exclamation point were actually making it into the shortcut for the history number!